# Tayama Video encoding (MPEG?)

Tags: password-recovery

I have a Tayama DVR CCTV system, with an administrator who's long gone and no password for the thing. I need to recover the footage for the month of July, 2010. There is a "Video" partition, which looks like it has the data I need- arranged by camera and date, but the files aren't anything I'm recognizing. Specifically, there are matching .Dat and .Idx files, but file doesn't recognize them as anything besides "Data".

From Tayama's documentation, I am led to believe the data is at some point stored as mpeg data, but I seem to be beyond my abilities to find arbitrary mpeg headers inside the files.

Either I need to break the programs's password features, or I need to decode their proprietary format. Either way, suggestions would be helpful.

PS. Tayama is less than helpful- I am a contractor working for the original customer, and the appliance is out of warranty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if ffmpeg/mplayer (mplayerhq.hu) recognise it, that's usually the easiest way.

I have had some security video that was completely unreadable by anything however; it appears that business is hiding in proprietairy formats...